# Are there linear transformations from vector spaces over different fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm in a matrix theory class, and today we started talking about linear transformations. My professor noted that the range and domain of a linear transformation must be vector spaces over the same field. This made sense to me at first because of the fields are different, then something like $T(cx)=cT(x)$ doesn't make any sense when c is only in one of the vector spaces.

But then I thought that maybe some fields might be compatible, like for example, $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$

*Are there any linear transformations for two spaces over different fields?* or *Are there functions that have all the same properties as linear transformations except that the spaces involved use different fields?*

If the answer is no, can you prove it?

Comment: What is mean "compatible"?

Comment: As in, $T(cx)$ and $cT(x)$ are both defined and also $T(cx)=cT(x)$

Comment: I haven't checked if $Z_5$ and $Z_5$ have a T such that $T(cx)=cT(x)$ but I mentioned them as candidates because $T(cx)$ and $cT(x) are both defined.

Comment: I still don't understand how it can be the same $c$ if fields are different. Explain me please.

Comment: @Weaam: do you understand that $5$ in $\mathbb Z_7$ and $5$ in $\mathbb Z_5$ are different things? Just ignore the fact they notated the same way. We can identify elements only in some rare cases (like isomorphism or embedding).

Comment: @Weaam: Yes, field extensions is the answer I wanted. Now TS can reformulate his question in more clear and rigorous way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an injective field endomorphism $\varphi$ from field $Fa$ to field $Fb$ - said differently:

$$\forall (x, y) \in Fa \times Fa, \varphi(a+b) = \varphi(a) + \varphi(b) \space \mathrm{and} \space \varphi(a.b) = \varphi(a).\varphi(b)$$

then $\varphi(Fa)$ is a sub field of $Fb$ isomorphic to $Fa$

If $Vb$ is a vector space over $Fb$ of finite dimension, you can exhibit a base from $Vb$. You can then build a sub set (not a sub vector space) of  $Vb$ from the base and the field $\varphi(Fa)$. This sub set (let us call it $Wb$) is a vector space over $\varphi(Fa)$ (*).

By identifying $Fa$ and $\varphi(Fa)$, you can indeed build a linear transformations (say $\Lambda$) from a vector space over $Fa$ (say $Va$) and $Wb$.

But you cannot call it a linear transformations from $Va$ to $Vb$ because $\Lambda(Va)$ is **not** a sub vector space of $Vb$ (except for the trivial $\Lambda(Va) = \{ 0_{Vb} \}$ see below). It is only a sub vector space of $Wb$.

---

Well to be honest, there is one trivial case where you could exhibit a *pseudo linear transformation* for $Va$ to $Vb$:

$$\begin{align}\Lambda: &Va \rightarrow Vb \\
&x \mapsto 0_{Vb}\end{align}$$

It respects all the properties for a linear transformation, and $\Lambda(Va) = \{ 0_{Vb} \}$ is indeed a sub vector space but it is not really interesting, and on a strict point of view, as the fields are different, it is **not** a true linear transformation.

(*) I suppose it could be extended to vector space of infinite dimensions, but I do not know how to prove it

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$ (i.e., an abelian group onto which $K$ acts). If $L$ is another field, and $K$ can act on the addtive structure of $L$ (i.e., the additive abelian group of $L$ is a $K$ vector space), then we can extend $V$ to a vector space over $L$ using tensor products. This construction is known as the extension of scalars. We take the tensor product of $V$ and $L$ over $K$:

$$V \otimes_K L$$

It is naturally both a $K$ vector space (by the tensor product constrution) and a $L$ vector space (by multiplication on the $L$ component). There is a natural function from $\varphi: V \to V\otimes_K L$, which is additive, and compatible with multiplication by scalars on $K$:

$$\varphi(x + y) = (x+y)\otimes 1 = (x\otimes 1) + (y\otimes 1)$$
$$\varphi(kx) = (kx\otimes 1) = (x\otimes 1_k) = k(x\otimes 1)$$

Here, $1_k$ detones the image of the action of $k$ on the unit of $L$.