# Why can't we define linear mapping over vector spaces over two different fields?

Tags: linear-transformations

When we study linear mapping in the chapter of vector space,  we see that if V and W be vector spaces over the same fields then $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear mapping provided it satisfies $ T(a\alpha + \beta)= aT(\alpha)+T(\beta) \forall \alpha, \beta \in V, a\in F$

Now let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and $W$ is a vector space over another field $E$ where $F\neq E$.

My question is,  what problem may arise if we try to define any linear mapping between these two?

The motivation behind this problem was to show there is no linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$ to $ \mathbb{R}(\mathbb{Q})$  however i am not getting any rigorous path to show this. What i was thinking can we get any kind of contradiction by any way?

Comment: How do you want to define it though? If $\alpha$ is a scalar in $F$ then how can you multiply a vector of $W$ by it?

Comment: In your first paragraph, I believe you mean "... over the *same* field".

Comment: Does this answer your question [Are there linear transformations from vector spaces over different fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1935772/721644) ?

Comment: Say, you have a morphism between the two fields, then you can use this morphism to get a notion of what you look for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there linear transformations from vector spaces over different fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935772/are-there-linear-transformations-from-vector-spaces-over-different-fields)

Comment: @NickD You are right. It was a mistake in typing indeed. Thank you so much for point out thw error

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem**

Note carefully that in the equation
$$T(a\alpha + \beta) = aT(\alpha) + T(\beta),$$
the operations on the left and right side are different.
To begin with, the $+$ on the LHS is the vector addition of $V$ and on the RHS is the one of $W$.

More importantly, the *scalar multiplication* $a\alpha$ is happening in $V$ and $aT(\alpha)$ in $W$.
This definition of scalar multiplication depends crucially on the field you are in.

For example, if $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ and $W$ over $\Bbb Q$, then given an $\alpha \in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, the product $\alpha w$ is not defined for $w \in W$.

---

**A Possible Solution**

You could, however, make sense of it if 
$$\Bbb F_1 \subset \Bbb F_2,$$
where $\Bbb F_1$ (resp., $\Bbb F_2$) is the field over which $V$ (resp., $W$) is a vector field.

However, this is nothing too enlightening as given any vector space over $\Bbb F_2$, it can naturally be made into a vector space over $\Bbb F_1$ by restricting the scalar multiplication.

---

**The Conclusion**

The takeaway is the following: When defining a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$, the only interaction that these objects have is via the scalar multiplication. (Which is a function from $\Bbb F \times V$ to $V$.)
Linear transformations are defined in a way so as to preserve this interaction. This is why you run into trouble when you change the fields for the "interactions" may not be compatible.